# Chrome: embedded pdfs overlays content (on some computers)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf, embed

I've got a problem using embedded pdfs inside websites with chrome (other browsers work as expected). Content, which is overlayed (like a lightbox) is disabled because the embedded pds overlays this content. Visually everything is correct, but code like hover, events, ... are not working.

I made a codepen https://s.codepen.io/stenet/debug/vzvxdq/mWkoNxYZZoGA to demonstrate the issue.

Here you can see the expected result: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18xXvIgEIzDPg1q99jfwif-nO28pC54SG/view?usp=sharing

Here you can see the wrong result: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kYWmGxRwKvSLNSL9Tk5ZmfyJsF97jifz/view?usp=sharing

As it just happens on some computers (same version of chrome installed!) I really don't know why this problem occurs. As far as I know chrome has its own pdf viewer.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Best regards, Stefan

Comment: Can you add your code so I can check where is the error and fix it?

Comment: You can find the code here: https://s.codepen.io/stenet/debug/vzvxdq/mWkoNxYZZoGA

Comment: Looks like it's a bug in chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=880122